# How to "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' into type 'string'" error?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create a C# program with two classes that will make a decision based on the user's input to output a response (ex. the user says rock and the computer says paper) that makes the user always lose. I currently have errors saying

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' into type 'string'" on lines
>   with all of the cases ("case1:", "case2:", "case3:").

Yet I have defined the "nameClassif" as a string just above. I also have a warning: Warning CS0649: Field 'Player.classif' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Tes
{
    class PlayerApp
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Player player1 = new Player();
            player1.PlayerChoice = InputValue();
            player1.Classif = InputValue();
            Clear();

            Write(player1);
            Write("\n\n\n\n");
            ReadKey();
        }

        public static string InputValue()
        {
            Write("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors:\t");
            return ReadLine();
        }

    }

    class Player
    {
        private string classif;


        // constructors
        public Player()
        { }

        public Player(string pC)
        {
            PlayerChoice = pC;
        }

        // properties
        public string PlayerChoice { get; set; }

        public string Classif { get; set; }

        public double SetFine()
        {
            if (classif == "rock")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose paper. You lose.");

            }

            else if (classif == "paper")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose scissors. You lose.");
            }

            else if (classif == "scissors")
            {
                WriteLine("The computer chose rock. You lose.");
            }


            return SetFine();
        }

public string ReturnNameOfClassification()
        {

            string nameClassif;
            switch (classif)
            {
                case 1: nameClassif = "rock"; break;
                case 2: nameClassif = "paper"; break;
                case 3: nameClassif = "scissors"; break;
                default:
                    WriteLine("Invalid selection..." +
                              " I assume you chose rock... :");
                    nameClassif = "rock - ???"; break;
            }
            return nameClassif;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n\n\n\t\tRock-Paper-Scissors" +
                "\nThe computer chose\t" + PlayerChoice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer based on your question title: `string a = 5;`

Comment: @John (OP john) Did any of the answers work for you? If so please mark one as the accepted answer using the checkmark below the down arrow.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you declare `classif` as a `string`, but you compare it to `int`:

```
private string classif;
switch (classif)
{
    case 1: nameClassif = "rock"; break; // 1 is an int, not a string!
}
```

In short: "5" is not equal to 5, nor is it comparable to 5. To fix this, you should compare like with like instead:

```
switch (classif)
{
    case "1": nameClassif = "rock"; break;
    case "2": nameClassif = "paper"; break;
    case "3": nameClassif = "scissors"; break;
    default:
        WriteLine("Invalid selection..." +
                  " I assume you chose rock... :");
        nameClassif = "rock - ???"; break;
}
```

Now the type you're comparing is the same as the type you're comparing it to, so the code works.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `switch` statement, the values in the case statement need to match the type of the variable you're switching on. You're switching on `classif`, which is a `string`, but your `case` statements are 1, 2, 3, which are `int`

Answer (score 0):

This one:

case 1, 2, 3 means an integer.. that's why it returns an error.

```
 case "1": nameClassif = "rock"; break;
  case "2": nameClassif = "paper"; break;
  case "3": nameClassif = "scissors"; break;
```